# Angular 14/+ FormBuilder not accepting RawValue of object while creating its FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I've this custom type `FormRawValue` that returns the JSON/RawValue of any AbstractControl

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
export type FormRawValue<T extends AbstractControl> = T extends AbstractControl<any, infer TRawValue> ? TRawValue : never;
```

and this simple `IPerson` interface:

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormRawValue } from './Forms.type';

export interface IPerson {
  id: FormControl<number>;
  name: FormControl<string>;
}

export type Person = FormRawValue<FormGroup<IPerson>>;
```

In the component code, I've a function that creates a new FormGroup using the JSON rawValue provided to it like this:

```
public map(data: Person) { // Person is simply the rawValue of IPerson

    let group = this._formBuilder.group<IPerson>(data as any); // works fine but bad appraoch
    let group1 = this._formBuilder.group<IPerson>(data); // should work because 'data' holds exactly the same thing that formBuilder is expecting.
  }
```

Please check my comments in above code block to understand the problem.

Please also check the running sample here: [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s38dz8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using something like this is the solution:

```
let group1 = this._formBuilder.group(data); // works fine
let group2: FormGroup<IPerson> = this._formBuilder.group(data); // works fine
```